# Is it possible to have Mutiple Bootstrapper classes in Prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism, bootstrapper

I am new to Prism. 
In my WPF(Uses Prism and Unity) project, I wanted to have 2 startup projects. If ProjectOne is selected as startup project, I wanted to load ModuleA, ModuleB and ModuleC. But if ProjectTwo is selected as startup project, I wanted to load ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleX and ModuleY.

Both Startup projects has its own ResourceDirectory to apply style and themes.

**Can I use different Bootstrapper classes for different projects?** If ProjectOne is selected as startup project, BootstrapperOne is called(from ProjectOne's App.xaml.cs's OnStartup) and If ProjectTwo is selected as startup project, BootstrapperTwo get invoked from ProjectTwo's App.xaml.cs's OnStartup.

Comment: this is wrong time to post I mean this time the persons who gives answers are les...better post the same in afternoon or in evening

Comment: @user1690002 - You definitely can have multiple bootstrapper's in your project. It's just what bootstrapper you run on start what that matters. Have you tried it out?

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I was able to create it.